# Where is the Azure Storage Account Location Variable/Constant

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage

I need to get the Azure Storage Account location EG (West Europe) for output, but can not seem to find it anywhere within azure-storage-php project.

[project location](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php)

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: the region of the container

Comment: Its in the build pipeline

Comment: Region is at the *storage account* level, not at the *container* level; all containers within a storage account will be in the same region.

Comment: @David Clews, any update on this issue?

Comment: it's a Microsoft trap, for turning users to .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the location, there is a method to get account property called [getStorageServiceProperties](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/30d469c163d43465a9c6e195526a3627abfdac12/src/ServiceManagement/Internal/IServiceManagement.php#L86), it will give you the account address.

However in my test I found it could only get the **classic** storage account property this sdk. If your account is not the **classic** it will response the 404 not found error.

[image]

So if your account is classic you could use this method, and if not you could change other language like [dotnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.storage.models.storageaccount?view=azure-dotnet), or you could choose to use the Rest API to get the property:[Storage Accounts - Get Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/getproperties).

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}?api-version=2019-06-01
```